# shifting of elements due to hover

Tags: html, css

I am creating a div in which elements are stacked on each other. The font-weight changes when I hover on the anchor tags in the div. The problem is, when the font-weight changes, it is shifting other elements as well. This is giving a very wobbly feeling to my div. what changes should I make to change the font-weight but not cause other elements to move. I am attaching part of my code for the same

```css
.discount{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.discount a{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400; /* Set the normal font weight */
}

.discount a:hover {
    font-weight: 700; /* Set the font weight on hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="discount">
      <a href="">Discount1</a>
      <a  style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount2</a>
      <a href="">Discount3</a>
      <a  style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount4</a>
      <a href="">Discount4</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.discount a{width: fit-content;}` add this css

Comment: in your snippets are no other elements that get shifted. would you mind putting said elements into the snipped too so that we can give an appropriate answer?

Comment: hey @jessman, yeah even I was surprised that there is no shifting in the code I provided above. However, for some reason, I can see it my original source. Coming to adding elements in the above code- it isn't much different from my original code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you could try to get around this issue.

### 1. Don't change the font weight

Changing font weight is essentially like using a different font so unfortunately, things will move. I know this sounds like it's avoiding the problem entirely but could you try animating opacity on hover instead so that the text goes from #000C to #000F to make it pop instead of font weight?

### 2. Static set the width

If your issue is the size of the container changing then you could set the width and/or height to a fixed amount to avoid it growing or shrinking when the font is changed.

### 3. Cheat by having 2 overlapping elements

Have 2 elements for each link; one behind the other and then fade the front link to reveal a link with the same text behind it with a thicker font weight behind it.

Answer (score 0):

When you're changing `font-weight`, the `line-height` **may** change as well (it depends on the actual font). That **may** cause element's `height` grow/shrink and vertically shift other elements. To avoid that, you might want to fix the `line-height`:

```css
.discount {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.discount a {
  line-height: 1.25rem; /* HERE */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* Set the normal font weight */
}

.discount a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  /* Set the font weight on hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="discount">
  <a href="">Discount1</a>
  <a style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount2</a>
  <a href="">Discount3</a>
  <a style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount4</a>
  <a href="">Discount4</a>
</div>
```

Another option would be adding `text-shadow` instead of changing `font-weight`. This approach eliminates both vertical and horizontal grow/shrink:

```css
.discount {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.discount a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* Set the normal font weight */
}

.discount a:hover {
  text-shadow: -.5px -.5px, .5px .5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount">
  <a href="">Discount1</a>
  <a style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount2</a>
  <a href="">Discount3</a>
  <a style="margin-bottom: 20px;" href="">Discount4</a>
  <a href="">Discount4</a>
</div>
```